# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: Please close pipeline or multi block before calling this method

Tags: redis, pipeline, jedis

I want page zrange,get error:Please close pipeline or multi block before calling this method.,how to solve this(My  cluster not support multi command https://github.com/CodisLabs/codis/blob/master/doc/unsupported_cmds.md)?

```
runWithPipeline(new JedisPipelinedCallback() {
  @Override
  public void execute(Pipeline pipeline) {
    int offset = 0;
    boolean finished = false;

    do {
      // need to paginate the keys
      Set<byte[]> rawKeys = pipeline.zrange(rawKnownKeysKey, (offset) * PAGE_SIZE, (offset + 1) * PAGE_SIZE - 1).get();
      finished = rawKeys.size() < PAGE_SIZE;
      offset++;
      if (!rawKeys.isEmpty()) {
        List<byte[]> regionedKeys = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        for (byte[] rawKey : rawKeys) {
          regionedKeys.add(getRegionedKey(rawRegion, rawKey));
        }

        pipeline.del(regionedKeys.toArray(new byte[regionedKeys.size()][]));
      }
      pipeline.sync();
    } while (!finished);

    pipeline.del(rawKnownKeysKey);
  }
});
```

// create {@link redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool} instance.

```
public static JedisPool createJedisPool(Properties props) {

    String host = props.getProperty(RedisConfig.HOST, "localhost");
    Integer port = Integer.decode(props.getProperty(RedisConfig.PORT, String.valueOf(Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT)));
    Integer timeout = Integer.decode(props.getProperty(RedisConfig.TIMEOUT, String.valueOf(Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT))); // msec
    String password = props.getProperty(RedisConfig.PASSWORD, null);
    Integer database = Integer.decode(props.getProperty(RedisConfig.DATABASE, String.valueOf(Protocol.DEFAULT_DATABASE)));

    log.info("create JedisPool. host=[{}], port=[{}], timeout=[{}], password=[{}], database=[{}]",
             host, port, timeout, password, database);

    return new JedisPool(createJedisPoolConfig(), host, port, timeout, password, database);
}
```

// create {@link redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig} instance.

```
private static JedisPoolConfig createJedisPoolConfig() {
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(256);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(2);
    return poolConfig;
}


Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();


private void runWithPipeline(final JedisPipelinedCallback callback) {
  final Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
  try {
    final Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
    callback.execute(pipeline);
    // use #sync(), not #exec()
    pipeline.sync();
  } finally {
    jedisPool.returnResource(jedis);
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue may be behind on caller of this method. Could you share how you handle the Jedis instance?

Comment: @JungtaekLim now,it's ok?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on this. Could you share your code which calls execute()? I'd like to see how Pipeline instance is initialized and relevant Jedis instance is handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is with this part of the code, where you try to retrieve value from pipeline using .get() method.

```
Set<byte[]> rawKeys = pipeline.zrange(rawKnownKeysKey, (offset) * PAGE_SIZE, (offset + 1) * PAGE_SIZE - 1).get();
```

When you issue a command(s) in pipeline you need to issue sync() command before retrieving values to execute all the commands that has been added to the pipeline, if you try to get values before issuing sync() it will throw error as above.

Solution:

```
Response<Set<byte[]>> temp = pipeline.zrange(rawKnownKeysKey, (offset) * PAGE_SIZE, (offset + 1) * PAGE_SIZE - 1);
pipeline.sync();
Set<byte[]> rawKeys = temp.get();
```

Comment: Yes I would like to address it but forgot to comment.